# Issues upgrading node - node-red-start not found

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red, raspberry-pi3

I've been trying to update node on my Raspberry Pi 3 that I use to run node-red.

Initially I updated node to 0.12 and during the installation saw the message removing node-red.
I tried to re-install using `npm install -g node-red` but could not run 'node-red-start'.

I then found the instructions for updating node [here](http://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi#manual-install) and followed them but I still cannot start node-red.

When I try `node-red-start` I get `node-red-start: command not found`.

the upgrade of node, npm and node-red seemed to work but I can't start it. I also need to set it up to start when the pi reboots.

Thanks

Comment: For general support questions like this, you can also make use of the project mailing list, linked at the bottom of nodered.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down on the page of instructions you linked to is a section called: 'Adding Autostart capability using SystemD'

That restores the node-red-start command and let's it auto start on boot using systemd.

Comment: Many thanks, I had missed that. I didn't realise the start-node-red was a 'special' way of starting that needed to be re-installed after replacing node. I'll give it a try.